# Support for monopod

Tags: lumia, apps, camera

Is monopod (selfie stick) with headphone jack supported in Windows Phone, or are there workarounds?

It looks the default camera is not supported. (cannot capture with "volume up" button)

(in particular the Lumia 630 and Monopod model Z07-55)

Comment: Have you tried emailing the company who makes it to ask about Windows Phone support?

Comment: @NeilTurner I didn't ask the company.I thought it should be independent of the model and there are some workarounds or apps available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS far as I can tell it is currently [not possible for developers to detect](https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/6522860-media-volume-changed-event-c) if the phone volume has changed - and therefore can't take a pcture then.

You could either look for Bluetooth remote controls that might be able to activate the shutter or you can make use of the self-timer in the Lumia Camera for now.